# $\omega$-nilpotent cover of a recurrent surface

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory

Theorem. Any $\omega$-nilpotent cover of a recurrent Riemannian manifold is Liouville.

$\omega$-nilpotent ($\Gamma=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}Z_{i}$, $Z_{i}$ normal in $\Gamma$, where $Z_{n+1}$ maps to the center of $\Gamma/Z_{n}$.)

The above theorem comes from a paper of T. Lyons and D. Sullivan.
[function theory random paths and covering spacesre](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214438681) (Theorem 2).

How to understand the $\omega$-nilpotent cover?

The second derived subgroup of the fundamental group of an open Riemann surface $X$ determines a covering space, is it $\omega$-nilpotent? (i.e. let $G=\pi_{1}(X)$, $G'=[G,G]$, $G''=[G',G']$, is the group $G/G''$ $\omega$-nilpotent?)

Comment: For $G$ free, $G/G''$ is free metabelian and hence has trivial center. Hence for $G$ free non-abelian, $G/G''$ is not hypercentral. (Your condition "$\omega$-nilpotent", which I'd call $\omega$-hypercentral, implies hypercentral.)